# How do I increase my daily quota limit for uploading videos through youtube api?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working for a news channel which uploads 50 videos per day. I have integrated youtube api on the website for the same purpose. There seems to be a quota limit of 6 videos per day. Is there any way I can purchase or get more quota limit? What is the process and charges for increasing the quota limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way of obtaining a quota extension for your application is that of addressing Google directly.

There's [this form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) that you'll have to fill in. Than wait for response -- which, according to the experience of users of this forum, doesn't arrive shortly.

Comment: Huge form. Thanks for sharing, will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with uploading videos but you should be able to ask for additional quotas for google apis on the IAM & ADMIN console view under Quotas (there should be a link from the developer dashboard under Quotas. Once there just select the quota you would like to change and submit a request.
Having said that, I have no experience with this process, so I don't know what is the involved in approving such a requests nor what kind of costs be involved.

Comment: Max limit allowance is the default 10,000. I'll try to contact them.